# Xcode (c++) : the Lower_bound function in the file including algorithm get an error

Tags: c++, xcode, algorithm

I tried to execute my code and i have an error in the file algorithm, with the lower_bound function.
Here is the part of my code where i use the lower_bound function :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include "NodeList.h"

const unsigned int NodeList::getSize() const
{
    return (unsigned int)_nodes.size();
}

Node * NodeList::getSmallestNode() const
{
    assert(!_nodes.empty());
    return _nodes.front();
}

void NodeList::removeSmallestNode()
{
    assert(!_nodes.empty());
    _nodes.pop_front();
}

void NodeList::addNode(Node* nodePt_)
{
    list<Node*>::iterator posIt = lower_bound<list<Node*>::iterator,      Node*, const bool(const Node*, const Node*)>
    (_nodes.begin(), _nodes.end(), nodePt_, Node::compare);
_nodes.insert(posIt, nodePt_);
}
void NodeList::displayAscending() const
{
    cout << "Liste de feuilles dans l'ordre croissant : " << endl;
    for (list<Node*>::const_iterator citPt = _nodes.cbegin(); citPt !=     _nodes.cend(); citPt++) {
    (*citPt)->display();
    }
}

void NodeList::displayDescending() const
{
    cout << "Liste de feuilles dans l'ordre decroissant : " << endl;
    for (list<Node*>::const_reverse_iterator critPt = _nodes.crbegin(); critPt != _nodes.crend(); critPt++) {
    (*critPt)->display();
    }
}
```

Here is the error i had in the file called at the beginning  :

**return __lower_bound<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __value_, __comp);**

**error** : No matching function for call to '__lower_bound'

Comment: The error is from _your_ code; look for "instancied from" lines in the compiler output.

Comment: You don't need any template parameters on the call to `lower_bound`

Comment: I suspect that `Node::compare` is a non-static member function. Post the *complete* error message.

Comment: Show declaration of `Node::compare`

Comment: please post an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve